# Calendar Extender Layout ASPX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, calendar

I am currently using this calendar extender in my ASPX page,

Currently, when I open the extender, it is displayed as shown below.

[image]

I would like to change the layout so that once the calender extender is opened, the first date on the right hand side will always be Monday (instead of Sunday), I have searched endlessly for how to do this and I have had no luck at all.

I am using VB with the page also.

If someone could give me some advice it would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FirstDayOfWeek` property

```
<asp:Calendar id="calendar1" runat="server"
       FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"/>
```

Further reading **[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.firstdayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)**

Comment: Ahhh good, I didn't know you could do this, I used WebControls.FirstDayOfWeek.Monday

Comment: Yes! you can also do it that way. Please accept the solution if you found it helpful so it can benefit future readers